# Win10, когда появляется источник звука - колонки делают "ПБМ"(глухой бас), причем очень громко. Как исправить?

Tags: windows, windows-10, аудио, драйвер, настройки

У жены на ноутбуке постоянно, как только в системе появляется источник звука - система бесится и как будто проверяет саму себя. Подскажите куда посмотреть, чтобы решить. Это очень громко, учитывая, что колонки 50 ватт.

**UPD:**

Подсказали в комментах попробовать драйвера родные поставить. Подскажите, есть ли софт какой-нить, который автоматом найдёт?

Comment: Я бы посмотрел в сторону драйверов. Проверить, какой стоит: родной для этой материнки/ноута или дефолтный виндовый? Из-за дефолтных часто бывают похожие проблемы. / Скачать нужный с сайта производителя, обновить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спс, попробую.

Comment: Софт для драйверов могу посоветовать - Driver Booster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Звуковую схему можно полностью выключить(на колонке) в той же вкладке, что чувак с ответа который не помог (Звуковая схема по умолчанию). Но придется включать и выключать каждый раз.

Возможно, люфтит разъем, но если такая штука только при подключении, то скорее всего это не оно и даже можете не проверять.

Если думаете про драйвера, то посмотрите версию realtek'а в устройствах и просто загуглите ваш realtek там сразу выдаст сайт с драйверами.

В настройках устройства еще есть тонкомпенсация, открываете колонки и заходите в улучшения и ищите, если нету, то скачиваете realtek драйвера.

https://www.realtek.com/en/directly-download?downloadid=366389f0a2313e73823a05ad24363061

Comment: в realtek есть автопоиск вот под 10-ку
https://www.realtek.com/en/directly-download?downloadid=366389f0a2313e73823a05ad24363061

Comment: Разъём не люфтит, проблема в системе. Вероятно в драйверах.

Comment: Там убунта ещё стоит - с ней проблем нет, так что точно не с железом проблема. Да и симптомы тонко намекают...

Comment: я понял вас, обновите драйвера и тонкомпенсацию включите, только нагуглите как это делается в линуксе, с этим я вам точно помочь не смогу, так как сам сижу виндовсе и линукс мне почти не нужен

Answer (score 2):

Галочку сними с "подключение устройства"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: точнее не галочку, а просто вместо стандартного выбери "нет" )

Comment: Не, речь немного не о том, не звук как при подключении USB устройства, там скорее ТуДум, А тут глухой басовый БПУМ. Но за наводку спасибо, это где-то в этих настройках живёт, ща поковыряюсь

Comment: Не помогло :( ..

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю видите ли вы мои комментарии, поэтому дропну еще один ответ:

Драйвера вот: https://www.realtek.com/en/agree-to-download?downloadid=cf287ca222612dd2f02b3a0c4baa609f

Под линукс* ищет автоматом.

Если скачанный архив не открывается накатите вот это 6.2.9:
https://www.kernel.org